# What is 2-FSK modulation?

Tags: rf, fsk

In the documentation for [a radio chip](http://focus.ti.com/docs/prod/folders/print/cc1110f32.html), I keep seeing the term 2-FSK, which seems to be a modulation scheme.

My understanding is that in FSK, data is encoded by emitting a carrier wave on a number of different frequencies. Is this right? How does this differ to 2-FSK?

Comment: What is the chip?

Comment: @Leon Heller - the Chipcon CC1110

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The number '2' refers to the number of tones used to encode the signal. For example, 2-FSK is essentially sending binary data using two frequencies. One symbol (time slice) has the potential for two values only. **2-FSK is usually what is meant by an unqualified mention of FSK**.

It's possible to use more than two tones. These modulation schemes usually are called [MFSK](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_frequency-shift_keying) for Multiple Frequency Shift Keying. A common MFSK scheme in amateur radio is MFSK16, which uses 16 different frequencies to represent 4 binary bits in each symbol. By your notation, this would be 16-FSK.

The more frequencies that you use in a symbol, the more complicated your modulation/demodulation circuit. Typical MFSK applications in amateur radio require a computer sound card and CPU for signal processing. Analog circuitry can be developed somewhat easily for FSK using two band-pass filters.

Answer (score 6):

I believe 2-FSK is just an encoding scheme that says:

- A "one" is encoded by transmitting a sine wave frequency f_1
- A "zero" is encoded by transmitting a sine wave with frequency f_2